Markdown mermaid code creating a split in flowchart
I am trying the below code on https://mermaid.live/
flowchart TD
  A{Condition 1}-->|True|,B{Condition 2}
  B{Condition 2}-->|True|,C[Do part 1]
  B{Condition 2}-->|False|,D[Do part 2]
  A{Condition 1}-->|False|,E[Do part 3]

However this is creating a split of the flow diagram which is not expected.
I have tried a workaround which worked partly but it is introducing two True paths for A{Condition 1} which is not desired again.
Workaround tried:
flowchart TD
  A{Condition 1}-->|True|,B{Condition 2}-->|True|,C[Do part 1]
  A{Condition 1}-->|True|,B{Condition 2}-->|False|,D[Do part 2]
  A{Condition 1}-->|False|,E[Do part 3]

Is there a way to fix the two "True" paths to have only one ?
Thanks!

Omit the commas after |True| and |False|.

It worked thanks, This can be closed!
